# How to Embed a LWC (lightning web component) within an Angular app (without Aura)?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, angular, embedded

I created a LWC (just a form) and now I need to embed it within my angular page.

One solution is to put my LWC inside an Aura compnent and then, use Lightning Out, **I do not want this** I just want to use LWC